# Custom sizes on multi preview xml

Tags: android, android-studio

With android studio 3.6 we can preview the xml in different sizes:

I need to **preview** a **custom size** 1.560 x 720, its possible to configure it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there’s a way to add a custom display on the Multi-Preview, but you can create a custom display on an emulator:

Just go to `Tools > AVD manager > Create Virtual Device > New Hardware Profile` and add your required dimensions.

[image]

Comment: I already knew this thanks, but I want to add my screen to the multi preview feature

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to preview your layout with the screen size you want, not view it with this size on the multi-window, it is still possible to do it from the *split* option on the top bar that appears when you edit your layout. Also on the Design one on the right of it if you don't want to see the code.

[image: icon location]

The way to change the size to your custom one is the same as before, you create your Hardware Profile from AVD or select it from the ones presets.

<s>If you want to see it on the *multi preview* tab, as I said on the comment to your first post, on android studio 4.0 [it will be possible to use custom sizes on multi-preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.0-multi-preview)</s>, I had not yet seen any tweak or info about doing it on android studio 3.6

Comment: Sadly this way you can't make the preview's tab float or convert it to a window which, in my case, is kind of problematic as I always type layouts and don't use the design tab

Comment: I think that android 4 will introduce Pixel devices and project locales but no custom devices

Comment: Yep, I just realized that understanded it wrong. Maybe they don't keep it to pixel ones on the future, I will edit my answers, sorry!